# How to reassign individual rows among multiple worksheets based on multiple cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I have four table-formatted worksheets (A, B, C, and D) each with rows of different data beneath matching column headers. I'm trying to write a VBA macro to cut rows from one sheet and paste them into the bottom of another based on the value of a single cell in a given column. I know this has been done from one individual sheet to another and I found the basic code to do so. However, I wanted to modify that to apply across all the worksheets, account for multiple permutations of the same value, and avoid re-checking rows that are already/have been placed in their "proper" worksheet, i.e., all rows marked 'Archived' in all its various permutations in column 17 of their respective other worksheets get shuffled over to the 'D' worksheet once the word archived is typed into that cell and the enter key is pressed. I think I'm screwing up something basic here with the "<>" and "or" portions, but not sure how to fix them. I'm also not sure if it is better to link this command to the 'Enter' keystroke or just have it check the values automatically?

```
Sub MoveRows()

Dim k As String
a = Worksheets(k).Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

    If Worksheet.Name <> "D" Then

            For i = 2 To a Step -1

                If Worksheets(k).Cell(i,17).Value = "Archived" or "archived" or "ARCHIVED" Then 
                    Worksheets(k).Rows(i).Cut
                    Worksheets("D").Range("A1").End(xldown).Offset(1,0).Insert  
                End If
            next i  
    Else 'do nothing'

End Sub
```

Comment: you will need to loop the sheets and test if the sheet name is not = "D"

Comment: thank you. would an If/then condition work?